# Input is not being taken

Tags: c#

Understanding:

- A Programm for someone that just started going to the Gym. (I'm trying
  to learn c#)
- First, the User fills out his Name, Age, Gender, Weight Height.
- Then The user Picks a Goal.

To get a better understanding, something along these lines happens. (after the steps above)

```
 if (Goal.GoalStatusGainWeight == true && Console.ReadLine() == "y")
        {
            Console.Clear();
            InitFiveByFive();

            //Caluclate Calories based on Gender and Goal
            GainWeight.ShowFoodsToGainWeight();
            Nutrition.CalcuateCalories();

            ExitToMenu();
        }
```

This is where my Problem is:

```
private static void ExitToMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PRESS ESC To Return to the MENU");
        var input = Console.ReadKey();

            if (input.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                InitMenu();

            }    

    }
```

Problem is when I get back to the Menu. And Input something again.

```
 do
        {
            var userInput = Console.ReadKey();

            try
            {
                switch (userInput.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.D1:
                        Console.Clear();
                        InitUser();
                        InitGoals();
                        Stats.ShowStats = true;
                        Menu.ShowMenu = false; 
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D2:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Menu.Disclamer();
                        Menu.ShowMenu = true;
                        Menu.ShowDiscalmer = true;
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D3:
                        Console.Clear();
                        Menu.MadeBy();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.Clear();
                        InitMenu();
                        break;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                throw;
            }

            if (Menu.ShowMenu == false)
            {
                Menu.MenuOnOff = false;
            }

        } while (Menu.MenuOnOff == true);
```

It will not take the input again. And I'm not sure how to handle the situation.
After the User Exists the 'Workout Plan' back to the Menu, and I try to Press 1 again, (`case ConsoleKey.D1:`) my Console App just closes.

I hope I got everything that you need to help me if there's something missing please let me know.

Thank you.

Comment: Menu.MenuOnOff should be equal to true

Comment: You mean after InitMenu(); right ? It does not do the trick, sadly.

Comment: I recommend you learn how to use the debugger - step through the code & check values at the point the code doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: It isn't taking input anymore, cause Menu.MenuOnOff is false

Comment: On case  `...D1` you set `Menu.ShowMenu = false` which in turn sets `Menu.MenuOnOff = false`, which ends the loop.
You simply setup your parameters on case `...D1` to close the menu.

Comment: Sorry, i don't really understand what you ment.